# App Script - Open Url in new Tab from Google WebApp (without assigned Spreadsheet)

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, url

I want to create a WebApp, that does the following:

1. User clicks button on WebApp to run script
2. Get User eMail
3. Create new Google Spreadsheet (name=eMail)
4. get Url of that Spreadsheet
5. Automatically open Url in new Tab

Step 5 is where I am stuck.
I have used `window.open(url)` before, however that only seems to work when you run code via a Spreadsheet. What I wanna do is displaying the button on my .html and run everything only with the WebApp but I can't do that because I can not use `SpreadsheetApp.getUi()` from that context.

Is there another way to do this?
Here is the Error im getting:
[image: Error]

**EDIT: Seems I had some minor mistakes in my Code.gs I think i fixed that now. Still same issue tho**

Thank you guys in advance! :)

Here is some sample code:

**Code.gs**

```
function doGet(e) {

  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("page");
}

function clickEvent () {
  const lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
  lock.tryLock(5000);
  if (lock.hasLock()){
  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

  var url = createFile(email);
  openUrl(url);  //THIS ONLY WORKED FROM WITHIN SPREADSHEET


  lock.releaseLock();
}
}

function createFile(email){
  var newSS= SpreadsheetApp.create(email);
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(newSS.getId());
  var url = file.getUrl();
  return url
}

function openUrl( url ){ //HAS TO CHANGE
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<html><script>'
  +'window.close = function(){window.setTimeout(function(){google.script.host.close()},9)};'
  +'var a = document.createElement("a"); a.href="'+url+'"; a.target="_blank";'
  +'if(document.createEvent){'
  +'  var event=document.createEvent("MouseEvents");'
  +'  if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("firefox")>-1){window.document.body.append(a)}'                          
  +'  event.initEvent("click",true,true); a.dispatchEvent(event);'
  +'}else{ a.click() }'
  +'close();'
  +'</script>'
  // Offer URL as clickable link in case above code fails.
  +'<body style="word-break:break-word;font-family:sans-serif;">Failed to open automatically. <a href="'+url+'" target="_blank" onclick="window.close()">Click here to proceed</a>.</body>'
  +'<script>google.script.host.setHeight(40);google.script.host.setWidth(410)</script>'
  +'</html>')
  .setWidth( 90 ).setHeight( 1 );
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog( html, "Opening ..." );
}
}
```

**page.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Click Button!</h1>
    <button id="btn">Run</button>

     <script>
      document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",sendRequest);

      function sendRequest(){
        google.script.run.clickEvent();
      }
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get url from app script and open spreadsheet in new tab wit JavaScript

Update app script function

```
function clickEvent () {
  const lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
  lock.tryLock(5000);
  if (lock.hasLock()){
    var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
    lock.releaseLock();
    return createFile(email);
  }
}
```

Also update JavaScript Code

```
function sendRequest(){
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler( 
    function (link) {
      window.open(link, '_blank').focus();
    }
  ).testCSV3();
}
```

Reference: [Communicate with Server Functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#index.html_1)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I have tried to implement your code. However it does not seem to work when I update the two functions.
Is it intentional that the SuccessHandler function `function (link)` does not have a name?

Comment: I had some minor mistakes in my Code so maybe the sequence was not clear. Do you think you can check again how I can open the url?

Comment: Please share your spreadsheet link.

Comment: Note: I have now tried to pass the Url-Variable to page.html as a Template but it does not work and i dont know why.

Comment: updated code link: [app script](https://script.google.com/macros/d/1yuuuara47iT3rXdcrIQvy5rF1tDg-lAlxPKzacYQkw2MgrO0N1SuKwjM/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Deployment link for testing https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzf9UHwdb_uK6y-10ykwLSe1tybIiNugiujhHuER8i36ognNUvJ/exec

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked for me!
Note: In my testing you dont need the alerts. So i commented them out so that the link opens directly upon clicking the Button.